# How to find all the blocks containing any specific element?

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, group-actions

This is an exercise problem from book on group theory by Dixon.

> **Exercise:** Find all the blocks containing 1 for the group

$$G=\langle(123456),(26)(35)\rangle \le S_6$$

where $\le $ is used for subgroup notation. One of the possible way is to compute all possible blocks (brute force way) and then check the membership of element 1 in all such blocks. Is there a better way to solve the exercise?

I am not getting from where to start please help or just provide a higher level idea how to proceed.

Comment: I think brute force is the only one way

Comment: It suffices to find all subgroups containing the point-stabiliser.

Comment: Btw, are you sure you copied it correctly? It's a little unusual to write (25)(35) like that, since this isn't in disjoint cycle notation.

Comment: @ verret Sorry for typo I have edited the question and did you mean that It suffices to find all subgroups containing the point-stabiliser of element 1?

Comment: What's with $\leq$? Was it supposed to mean \subset ($\subset$), or \subseteq ($\subseteq$), or maybe \subsetneq ($\subsetneq$)?

Comment: $\leq$ in this context means subgroup.

Comment: Anyway, in your particular case, the second generator acts by conjugation on the first element as inversion, so this is the dihedral group of degree $6$, in its natural action. You can use this to find the blocks (or yes, find all the subgroups containing the stabiliser of 1).

Comment: @verret Could you please elaborate more (high level idea) on, how to proceed after finding all the subgroups containing the stabiliser of 1?

Comment: For each such subgroup, find the orbit of 1 under it, that will give you all the blocks (once each, its a 1-1 correspondence)..

Comment: @verret I think this subgroup $\langle (26)(35)\rangle$ contain stabiliser of 1. Is it true?

Comment: Yes, in fact, it is the stabiliser of 1. The orbit of 1 under it is just {1}, so that gives one block containing 1.